Pass lambda to templated function with deduced types
I have the following example with two versions of make function that accepts another function and deduces the argument types. Then it creates a struct of a templated Signature type with that function.
enum class SomeEnum {
     ONE = 1,
     TWO = 2,
};

template <SomeEnum _Type, typename _Result, typename... _Args>
struct Signature {
  static constexpr SomeEnum Type = _Type;
  using Result = _Result;
  using Args = std::tuple<_Args...>;

  std::function<_Result (_Args...)> func;
};

template <
    SomeEnum _Type,
    typename _Result,
    typename... _Args>
Signature<_Type, _Result, _Args...> make(
    std::function<_Result (_Args...)> func) {
  return Signature<_Type, _Result, _Args...>{.func = func};
}

template <SomeEnum _Type, typename _Result, typename... _Args>
Signature<_Type, _Result, _Args...> make(
    _Result (*func)(_Args...)) {
  return Signature<_Type, _Result, _Args...>{
      .func = std::move(func)};
}

void foo(int x, std::string y, int z) {
}

auto sig1 = make<SomeEnum::ONE>(&foo);

auto sig2 = make<SomeEnum::TWO>([](int x, std::string y, int z) {
});

This version works:
auto sig1 = make<SomeEnum::ONE>(&foo);

but this version:
auto sig2 = make<SomeEnum::TWO>([](int x, std::string y, int z) {
});

Does not
main.cpp:40:13: error: no matching function for call to 'make'
auto sig2 = make<SomeEnum::TWO>([](int x, std::string y, int z) {
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:23:37: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'std::function<_Result (_Args...)>' against '(lambda at main.cpp:40:33)'
Signature<_Type, _Result, _Args...> make(
                                    ^
main.cpp:29:37: note: candidate template ignored: could not match '_Result (*)(_Args...)' against '(lambda at main.cpp:40:33)'
Signature<_Type, _Result, _Args...> make(
                                    ^
1 error generated.

However, if I explicitly set type, then it works:
std::function<void(int x, std::string y, int z)> l = [](int x, std::string y, int z) {
};

auto sig2 = make<SomeEnum::TWO>(l);

How can I make this version:
auto sig2 = make<SomeEnum::TWO>([](int x, std::string y, int z) {
});

work? I would like to be able to just pass the lambda with additional typing and have the code deduce the types.

Implicit conversions are not considered for purposes of template argument deduction. If you only leave the overload taking std::function, make<SomeEnum::ONE>(&foo); doesn't work either, even though std::function has a constructor taking a function pointer. Simpler repro. The compiler can't go "let's consider an infinite number of possible instantiations of std::function, in hopes of finding one that can be constructed from this lambda". (Besides, there's in fact more than one such.)

You moved a function pointer but didn't move the std::function parameter, looks like a typo.

Why does the implicit type conversion not work in template deduction?. That is why you have to explicitly specify the type. Implicit type conversion with template

The question was closed by saying it's a duplicate, but it points me to simpler explanations that don't have a param pack. I understand why this doesn't work, but it doesn't help me, because I don't know how to rework this to make it work.

std::function supports CTAD (via its deduction guides), but CTAD doesn't apply to function parameters.
So your parameter type must be templated (instead of being std::function<__>):
template <typename F> void foo(F &&func) {bar(std::function(std::forward<F>(func)));}

Where bar accepts std::function<R(P...)>, like your first overload of make().

If I added a templated argument it doesn't deduce either. I would need a longer example to see what you mean.

@gruszczy https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/54Kzh9rT4

I am afraid this is not enough. My example is much more complex and just adding typename F for func doesn't work. I need to capture the argument types and have additional parameters. I tried adding just typename F inside, but it doesn't deduce in this case.

@gruszczy I do infer the argument types from the lambda, I even print them. Isn't that what you want? Can you perhaps make a [mcve] of your attempt to implement my suggestion, and how it doesn't work?
